# QR TAG - iCal and Vcard

Tags: php, qr-code, icalendar, vcf-vcard

Is it possible to create a QR Code tag that sends a vCard and dynamically adds an event to the calendar that is based on today's date + 90 days?

Comment: do you know of any generators that can do both in the same tag?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a "VEVENT" (a type of vCard)

```
BEGIN:VEVENT
SUMMARY:My Event
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20120125
DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20120126
LOCATION:Hollywood
DESCRIPTION:Having a party
END:VEVENT
```

The date is written as YYYYMMDD - so you can set it for 90 days in the future.
However, there's no way to create a code which has both a calendar and addressbook entry.

At best, you could put the email address into the DESCRIPTION field.

Answer (score 1):

What if you sent the qr code to a landing page where it identified it was a smartphone and then send it a vcard and a vcalendar event?  Then you could theoretically send the phone all the data you want once it visits your page with programming.